Lights are flickering
Some of the lights in my home will flicker and dim themselves at what seems to be random. This has been going on for at least the 3 years we have been in the house. Video of a lamp flickering
Things to note:

Noticed on both ceiling lights and lamps plugged into outlets.

Haven't noticed any power fluctuation in any other electronics.

Lights are not on a dimmer switch.

Most commonly occurs in the evening, although that could just be when we notice since the lights are on.

Lights are on different breakers.

This will happen off and on. One night a light will be so dim it's almost off and flickering, the next day it'll work fine.


Any ideas on what could be causing this? Or any ideas on what I could try to fix it? Let me know if you need any additional information. Appreciate your help!

This is the third question about flickering lights this week. Are we seeing reposts?

Yeah, that looks like series arcing to me.  Does your insurer offer the Ting home energy monitor?  It looks for that.  Also, do you have a wild hair to change all the receptacles and switches to a different style, while carefully using a torque screwdriver to set screw torques correctly?  If you don't, consider getting such a wild hair, and if you already did without the torque screwdriver, revisit.

The next time this happened I was able to use a multimeter and found that the outlets were going from 113v to 112v when flickering. When working normally they were 120v.
The next day it got BAD! Some outlets and lights wouldn't work at all, others only getting 68v. TVs and appliances were turning off and on this time, so we asked our neighbors if they were by chance having the same issue and they were.
Turns out one of the power lines in the backyard had been slowly burning, and that night the line snapped and fell to the ground. Power company came out that night to repair the line, no issues since.
TL;DR the issue was one of the power lines outside burning down.

Congrats on a self answer! Be sure to click the checkmark on your answer so folks know it was the fix.

That flickering looks  a lot like loose connections to me.  But it could also be brown outs because of what is being used by your neighbours.
Complain to your power company.  They should have a service for testing the quality of power.  Some have instruments they can lend to you.
If you are comfortable using a multimetre in a power socket, you can check the voltage when this is happening.
As mentioned in the comment, LED lights are more sensitive to power fluctuations, especially voltage.  Dimmable LED fittings (not the lamps by themselves) are also sensitive (whether you have a dimmer attached to them or not).  I have had worse flickering whenever my solar kicked in.  When I measured the mains, it was almost 240V on solar, but 220V on grid.  I removed the dimmers and replaced the LED fittings with non dimmable ones.
